# ListBox with two ItemsSource and DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, xpath, data-binding, listbox, xmldataprovider

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm not finding the solution. how do I bind to two arrays within a data source with one ListBox?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ConfigurationData" XPath="Configuration/Component">
    <x:XData>
        <Configuration xmlns="">
            <Component ID="2252371">
                <ComponentAttribute ID="301080453">
                    <Name>ColorHexCodes</Name>
                    <Value />
                    <Values>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#FFFFFA</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#A80000</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                        <Value>#D1D3D4</Value>
                    </Values>
                </ComponentAttribute>
                <ComponentAttribute ID="301080500">
                    <Name>ColorDescription</Name>
                    <Value />
                    <Values>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>0010 - White</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>1902 - Red</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                        <Value>3971 - Silver</Value>
                    </Values>
                </ComponentAttribute>
            </Component>
        </Configuration>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

What I need to show is the list that shows the ColorDescription and ColorHexCodes side by side. These two collections will always line up.

I came up with this:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource ConfigurationData}" XPath="//ComponentAttribute[Name='ThreadDescription']/Values/*" />
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Swatch">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" FontSize="14" Foreground="CadetBlue">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding XPath="//ComponentAttribute[Name='ColorDescription']/Values/Value" />
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="14" Foreground="CadetBlue">
                    <TextBlock.DataContext></TextBlock.DataContext>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding XPath="//ComponentAttribute[Name='ColorHexCodes']/Values/Value" />
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It renders the correct number of ListBoxItems, but is only displaying the first value in each item. Where am I going wrong? I know this has to be something really easy I'm just missing.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the use of a [Composite Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405.aspx) storage which can hold both of your lists, but be used to be bound to by one listbox and handle each item *type* specifically.

The link to MSDN gives an example of showing two different data items in one display.